# How to remove __main__. in Python error handling

Tags: python, custom-error-handling

I am trying to generate custom exception in Python. Below is my code.

```
class numerror(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self):
        message = "invalid number"
        dict = {'nmerror': message}
        err = json.dumps(dict)
        super().__init__(err)
        

        .
        .
        except numerror as e:
        return e
```

Below is the output.

```
{'error': __main__.numerror('{"nmerror": "invalid number"}')}
```

I want to remove `__main__.numerror` and expected output is below.

```
'{"nmerror": "invalid number"}'
```

Is there anyway to achieve this. Thankyou.

Comment: The `e` is a `numerror` object.  You can print whatever fields you need out of that object.

Comment: The output of **what**? In any case, if you caught your exception, and want the message you created, you can retrieve it at `e.args[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The `__main__` in there is a qualified name + class name, which is displayed as part of the `repr` of an exception.

It is not an "output" per se: if you want to check that in code, you should retrieve the exception `.args`  attribute. If the excetpion is being printed and you want to filter that in the output, however, you can simply create a new `__repr__` method for your custom exception:

```
class numerror(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self):
        message = "invalid number"
        dict = {'nmerror': message}
        err = json.dumps(dict)
        super().__init__(err)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.args[0])
```